# How to append classNames/attributes when extending views

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

```
var MyView1 = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
   className: "MyView1",
   attributes: { 'data-view': 'MyView1' }
});


var MyView2 = MyView1.extend({
   className: "MyView2",
   attributes: { 'data-view': 'MyView2' }
});
```

MyView1 is `<div class="MyView1" data-view="MyView1">`
MyView2 is `<div class="MyView2" data-view="MyView2">`

How to make MyView2 =
`<div class="MyView1 MyView2" data-xxx="MyView1" data-yyy="MyView2">`?

If impossible, this is also ok
MyView1 =  `<div class="MyView1" data-view="MyView1"`
MyView2 =  `<div class="MyView1" data-view="MyView1" data-another-attrib="MyView2">`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`className` can be defined as a function and evaluated at runtime. From [the Backbone docs](http://backbonejs.org/#View-extend):

> Properties like tagName, id, className, el, and events may also be defined as a function, if you want to wait to define them until runtime.

So you could look-up the result of the parent class's `className` and append the new class to it. Make sure you use `_.result` to evalutate the parent's className incase it is also a function.

```
var MyView2 = MyView1.extend({
   className: function(){
       return _.result(MyView2.__super__, 'className') + " MyView2";
   },
   attributes: { 'data-view': 'MyView2' }
});
```

Alternatively, you could just add the two classes to MyView2's `className`:

```
var MyView2 = MyView1.extend({
   className: "MyView1 MyView2",
   attributes: { 'data-view': 'MyView2' }
});
```

Update - from the comments. You can also dig out the `className` from MyView1 as well:

```
var MyView2 = MyView1.extend({
   className: MyView1.prototype.className + " MyView2",
   attributes: { 'data-view': 'MyView2' }
});
```